# Check if php get variable is set to anything?

Tags: php, get, strlen

I need to check if variables are set to something. Up till now I have been using **strlen()**, but that is ***really embarrassing*** as I am pretty sure that is not a very efficient function to be using over an over again.

How do I perform this sort of check more efficiently:

```
if (strlen($_GET['variable']) > 0)
{
    Do Something
}
```

Note that I don't want it to do anything if `$_GET['variable'] = ''`

Just to clarify what I mean - If I had `www.example.com?variable=&somethingelse=1` I wouldn't want it to penetrate that if statement

Comment: This is not embarrassing, it works as you wish and is readable and understandable.

Comment: Just to clarify what I mean - If I had www.example.com?variable=&somethingelse=1 I wouldn't want it to penetrate that if statement

Comment: Awww I try not to be embarrassed with my scripting but it is hard at times!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try `empty`.

```
if (!empty($_GET['variable'])) {
  // Do something.
}
```

On the plus side, it will also check if the variable is set or not, i.e., there is no need to call `isset` seperately.

There is some confusion regarding not calling `isset`. From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/empty).

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

and...

> That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Comment: @Winston, from the [documentation](http://in3.php.net/empty): A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Comment: you're right! Sorry... But earlier, if you wrote like this, it might throw notice.

Comment: @Winston, I used to be confused by this too, but I have seen this in use since a long time without any notice (and I always keep `error_reporting` at its highest). Any idea which version might have made this change?

Comment: Yes what I saw in the php documentation was it said it was changing what empty() responds to between versions - hardly inspiring confidence

Comment: @AmyNeville, where? I don't see this behaviour listed in the changelog in the documentation. The closest is change in `5.0.0` where "Objects with no properties are no longer considered empty." But I don't think this applies to your scenario.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to accept this answer. I think this is the correct one - thanks everyone and hw...:)

Comment: `or if its value equals FALSE` - this might cause heavy problems, if you send 0 as parameter value.

Comment: @marinj agreed, for me, i used isset($_GET['value']) because value could be zero which is acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 8):

```
 if(isset($_GET['variable']) && $_GET['variable']!=""){

}
```

Comment: what if an input will have `value = ""` isset will be true but still empty

Comment: And yes, thats what the Q wanted: __Note that I don't want it to do anything if $_GET['variable'] = ''__

Comment: @AxelAmthor, but the code above will do something if value = "". It is set, so the if condition will be `true`.

Comment: This seems like it would work now and be a bit more efficient than strlen probably hmmmm. So apparently there's no in-build function for this sadly :)

Comment: @AmyNeville, actually, there is an inbuilt function: `empty`, as explained in my answer below.

Comment: isset - Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.            empty -  Determine whether a variable is empty.                  empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check if any $_GET is set, without knowing the value just count the $_GET array:

```
<?php
if (count($_GET) == 0):
    // do your stuff
else:
    // do your other stuff
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_GET['variable']) && !empty($_GET['variable']))
{
//Do Something
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `isset` if you are going to use `empty`. You can see my answer for details or check the [documentation](http://in3.php.net/empty).

Answer (score 0):

You can use check for `isset()` but i would rather check also for not blank character with  `!= ''`

```
if (isset($_GET['variable'])) && ($_GET['variable']) != '')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about just

```
if ($_GET['variable'])
{
     Do Something
}
```

Comment: or maybe: if ($_GET['variable'] != "")